# Method must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments, canvas

I am trying to draw circles in the canvas. Currently I can do it on button click, but I also need to do the same when the `Fragment` is loaded. Below is my `Fragment` code.

```
public class StepTwentyOneFragment extends Fragment {

    private CanvasView customCanvas;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.step21_fragment, container, false);
        customCanvas=(CanvasView)v.findViewById(R.id.signature_canvas);

        final Button button1=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.step18button1);


        float radius=(customCanvas.getCanvasWidth()/2) - ((customCanvas.getCanvasWidth()/2)/100)*60;
        new MyAsyncTask(customCanvas).execute();

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(v.getId()==R.id.step18button1){

                    float radius=(customCanvas.getCanvasWidth()/2) - ((customCanvas.getCanvasWidth()/2)/100)*60;
                    customCanvas.drawCircle(radius);
                    Log.d("An_Width", "" + customCanvas.getCanvasWidth());
                    Log.d("An_Height" ,""+ customCanvas.getCanvasHeight());

                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border_5);
                    button1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);


                }
            }
        });






        return v;
    }

    public static StepTwentyOneFragment newInstance() {

        StepTwentyOneFragment f = new StepTwentyOneFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }


    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser) {
            Activity a = getActivity();
            if(a != null) a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
    }

    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        CanvasView myTaskView;

        MyAsyncTask(CanvasView v){
            myTaskView = v;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            myTaskView.drawCircle(150);
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Below is my `Canvas` Code

```
public class CanvasView extends View {

    public int width;
    public int height;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    Context context;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOLERANCE = 5;
    private int canvasHeight, canvasWidth;
    private float radius;

    public CanvasView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);
        context = c;

        mPath = new Path();

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    }

    // override onDraw
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        mCanvas=canvas;

        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle_1);

        canvasHeight= canvas.getHeight();
        canvasWidth= canvas.getWidth();

        Log.d("Height - "," / "+canvas.getHeight());
        Log.d("Width - "," / "+canvas.getWidth());

//         DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
//        ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
//        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
//        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        float h=canvasHeight/2;
        float w=canvasWidth/2;


        d.setBounds(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        d.draw(canvas);

        canvas.drawCircle(w, h, radius, mPaint);
    }

    public void clear2(){
        radius=0;
        //important. Refreshes the view by calling onDraw function
        invalidate();

    }

    public void drawCircle(float radius1) {

        radius=radius1;
        //important. Refreshes the view by calling onDraw function
        invalidate();

    }

    public int getCanvasHeight()
    {
        return canvasHeight;
    }

    public int getCanvasWidth()
    {
        return canvasWidth;
    }

}
```

However in my `Fragment`, inside the `MyAsyncTask`, it shows the error `Method drawCircle must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker` for the code line  `myTaskView.drawCircle(150);`

How can I fix this?

Comment: `myTaskView.drawCircle(150);` line causing issue before calling drawcircle from non UI Thread

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK: Right, how to fix it?. calling that part directly from `onCreate` didn't do anything, so I think it has to be inside this thread to draw the circle when the fragmnet is loaded?

Comment: Move it in onPostExecute method

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK: Thanks, where is this method is located?

Comment: Barrier, my question is why u are using `AsyncTask ` ? i think no need to use if you are using it just to call `myTaskView.drawCircle(150);`. and onPostExecute method in avalaible in `AsyncTask`  class so just override it in same way as u have done for `doInBackground `

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK : It is not working . Any suggestions .

Answer (score 2):

You can not show anything on UI thread if you are implementing in doInBackground(). Its is for background task. To update your UI you must implement your methods in postexecute().

Read more about AsyncTask : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Clear your concepts then it will be easier to use AsynTask.

**Basic structure of AsyncTask :**

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Where is this `onPostExecute` method?

Comment: @Barrier see edited answer. onProgressUpdate() is optional if you want to show any progress of work.

Comment: what are the parameters I should pass? I have no parameters at all

Comment: @Barrier if there are no parameters then you should pass Void as parameters.

Comment: Prepared it as you described. The circle is not yet getting drawn

Comment: @Barrier you dont have to use AsyncTask if you just want to draw a circle. Call that method in fragment onCreateView() method if you just want to draw circle when the fragment is opened.

Comment: It is not working . So that's why I use an AsyncTask class.